# Scripting in Delphi application

Tags: sql-server, delphi, scripting

i develop a BPM software and I would like to add end user scripting logic.

I try to express myself with an example.

in a Process there are 2 variables (Price, ApplyDiscount, DicountAmount, Total).

somehow the user wants to define this logic:

```
//Delphi code for explanation:
if ApplyDiscount then
  Total := Price * DiscountAmount
else
  Total := Price;
```

since my app is a SQL Server Client server app i thought also about the idea to run a query with parameters so the user uses SQL syntax to script the logic and it will work.
I need to define the details but somehow the idea is to use the `:Parameter` syntax to allow the script pass and recieve values from my application.

This is for sure ok, but i was wondering if there is another way to do it without writing my scripting engine.

Thanks.

Comment: I heard about this: http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx it could be a solution, i like the idea that the scripting language is "pascal-ish" or "sql-ish" since my users already use pascal (inside Report Builder reports - RAP language) and sql (for querying the DB and create rerports), so adding another language would make it too complex for the end user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some scripting engines for Delphi:

- [DelphiWebScript](http://delphitools.info/dwscript/)  which is my preferred: it has the best syntax, is probably the faster, and is Open Source;
- [PascalScript](http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx);
- [TMS Scripter Studio](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/scriptstudio.asp).

If you want "non pascalish" scripting, you can take a look at [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) which is pretty simple to work with.

*Edit*:

Some additional candidates:

- [SEPI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sepi);
- [ScriptEngineII](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scriptengine2/);
- [BESEN](http://code.google.com/p/besen/) which is a JavaScript engine written in Delphi, including JIT!
- [SpiderMonkey for Delphi](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-javascript/) also executing JavaScript.

Comment: TMS solution is more complete since it comes with a kind of IDE for the end user, but the other 2 seem very promising. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have an IDE in DWS (in a sub folder of the source code repository) - pretty basic, but working and ready to be integrated in your code.